# Azure B2C - Custom Policy - OAuth2 Technical Profiles - Can I create a claim from an auth endpoint response query string parameter

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using an [OAuth2 Technical Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/oauth2-technical-profile) in a Azure B2C custom policy to allow my users to authenticate with a third party OAuth provider.

The ClaimsProvider looks something like this:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>app.example.com</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Example OAuth2</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Example-OAuth2">
      <DisplayName>Example OAuth2</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
      <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://example.com/token</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://example.com/oauth2</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://example.com/userinfo</Item>
        <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>            
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">domainspecific openid email profile</Item>

        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">client-id</Item>

        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
        <Item Key="ResolveJsonPathsInJsonTokens">true</Item>
        <Item Key="AccessTokenResponseFormat">json</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="ClientSecretFile" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="familyName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="domain.com" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderTenantId" PartnerClaimType="domainTenantId" />
        
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderAccessToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderRefreshToken" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:refresh_token}"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
    </TechnicalProfile>

  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

This works with one exception, the *identityProviderTenantId* is never set. The source of this, domainTenantId, is available in two locations:

1. It is returned as part of the query string when the third party provider calls back to the B2C OAuth2 redirect URI:

   https://ourdomain.b2clogin.com/ourdomain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp?code=546fghfgh-fghjdfgdhjg&state=someState&**domainTenantId=464755345674**
2. It is available in the idToken which is returned as part of the response from the access token endpoint:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=10002000
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8

{
 "refreshToken": "RefreshTokenContent",
 "accessToken": "AccessTokenContent",
 "expires_in": 3600,
 "x_refresh_token_expires_in": 8726400,
 "idToken": "IDTokenContent"
}
```

I have been unable to return the **domainTenantId** as a custom claim despite many attempts including:

1. Just returning it as a standard OutputClaim:

   `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderTenantId" PartnerClaimType="domainTenantId" />`
2. Trying to return it using a ClaimResolver:

   `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderTenantId" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:domainTenantId}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />`

   or

   `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderTenantId" PartnerClaimType="{OAUTH-KV:domainTenantId}" />`
3. Trying to extract the idToken from the access token response

   `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProviderIdentityToken" PartnerClaimType="idToken"/>`

   (identityProviderIdentityToken is never set in this case)

I have also tried using the OpenIdConnect protocol. This does return the **domainTenantId** as a simple OutputClaim ***but*** won't return the refresh token, which we also need for our app to work correctly.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: I am facing the same issue and have not been able to resolve it. Any updates on this?

Comment: I'm afraid not, it is still an issue. We have had discussions with the Microsoft B2C product team and they have confirmed that what we are trying to do isn't currently possible with B2C, partly because returning additional query parameters in the authresp callback is not standards compliant.

Comment: There seem to be two available solutions:
1. Work with the third party provider to provide the tenant ID via some other endpoint
2. Persuade Microsoft product team to return the refresh token when using the OpenIdConnect protocol (see https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/8cc30647-99ec-ec11-a81b-6045bd796569)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by calling two OAuth2 technical profiles consecutively.

The first on has /me as the claims endpoint, whereas the second one has /organization as the claims endpoint. The second call has the user's tenantId in the response.

---

First technical profile:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AADCommon-OAuth2-First">
                <DisplayName>some display name</DisplayName>
                <Description>some description</Description>
                <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
                <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token</Item>
                    <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize</Item>
                    <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me</Item>
                    <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointAccessTokenName">access_token</Item>
                    <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
                    <Item Key="client_id">xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</Item>
                    <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
                    <Item Key="scope">openid profile offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read</Item>
                    <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <CryptographicKeys>
                    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_AADSecret" />
                </CryptographicKeys>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="givenName" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="surname" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="displayName" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
                    
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isMicrosoftSignInInvoked_FLAG_LOCAL" DefaultValue="true" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" /> <!-- This flag invokes the second OAuth2 call -->
                </OutputClaims>
                <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Social" />
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

---

Second technical profile:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AADCommon-OAuth2-Second">
                <DisplayName>some display name second</DisplayName>
                <Description></Description>
                <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
                <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token</Item>
                    <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize</Item>
                    <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization</Item>
                    <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointAccessTokenName">access_token</Item>
                    <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
                    <Item Key="client_id">xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</Item>
                    <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
                    <Item Key="scope">openid profile offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read</Item>
                    <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <CryptographicKeys>
                    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_AADSecret" />
                </CryptographicKeys>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" DefaultValue="TENANT ID UNSET" Required="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oauth2Access_token" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:access_token}" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oauth2Refresh_token_rawJSON" PartnerClaimType="{oauth2:refresh_token}"  /> <!-- this is the refresh token returned as json -->
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oauth2Refresh_token" /> <!-- this claim is transformed by the OutputClaimstransformations by extracting the refresh token's value from JSON -->
                    
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="organizationEndpointResponseValueCollection_LOCAL" PartnerClaimType="value"  /> <!-- string collection from the JSON response of /organization endpoint -->
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="organizationEndpointResponseValueCollectionSingleValue_LOCAL" /> <!-- first (and only) object from the string collection from the JSON response of /organization endpoint -->
                </OutputClaims>

                <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <!-- refresh token extraction -->
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetRefreshTokenClaimFromJson" />

                    <!-- extract tenant id -->
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ExtractSingleValueObjectFromValueCollection" />
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetTenantIdFromValueObjectJson" />
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="FormatIdentityProviderFromTenantId" />
                </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

---

The used claims transformations:

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="ExtractSingleValueObjectFromValueCollection" TransformationMethod="GetSingleItemFromStringCollection">
            <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="organizationEndpointResponseValueCollection_LOCAL" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
            </InputClaims>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="organizationEndpointResponseValueCollectionSingleValue_LOCAL" TransformationClaimType="extractedItem" />
            </OutputClaims>
        </ClaimsTransformation>

        <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetTenantIdFromValueObjectJson" TransformationMethod="GetClaimFromJson">
            <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="organizationEndpointResponseValueCollectionSingleValue_LOCAL" TransformationClaimType="inputJson" />
            </InputClaims>
            <InputParameters>
                <InputParameter Id="claimToExtract" DataType="string" Value="id" />
            </InputParameters>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" TransformationClaimType="extractedClaim" />
            </OutputClaims>
        </ClaimsTransformation>

        <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetRefreshTokenClaimFromJson" TransformationMethod="GetSingleItemFromJson">
            <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oauth2Refresh_token_rawJSON" TransformationClaimType="inputJson" />
            </InputClaims>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oauth2Refresh_token_rawJSON_key" TransformationClaimType="key" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oauth2Refresh_token" TransformationClaimType="value" />
            </OutputClaims>
        </ClaimsTransformation>
```

---

The extended claims schema:

```
<ClaimType Id="organizationEndpointResponseValueCollection_LOCAL">
            <DisplayName>Value field from response from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization</DisplayName>
            <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
        </ClaimType>
        
        <ClaimType Id="organizationEndpointResponseValueCollectionSingleValue_LOCAL">
            <DisplayName>Single object from the value field from response from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization</DisplayName>
            <DataType>string</DataType>
        </ClaimType>
        
        <ClaimType Id="isMicrosoftSignInInvoked_FLAG_LOCAL">
            <DisplayName>isMicrosoftSignInInvoked</DisplayName>
            <DataType>boolean</DataType>
            <AdminHelpText>Whether the user has selected sign in with Microsoft</AdminHelpText>
        </ClaimType>

        <ClaimType Id="oauth2Refresh_token_rawJSON">
            <DisplayName>oauth2:refresh_token</DisplayName>
            <DataType>string</DataType>
            <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
        </ClaimType>

        <ClaimType Id="oauth2Refresh_token_rawJSON_key">
            <DisplayName>oauth2:refresh_token_raw_key</DisplayName>
            <DataType>string</DataType>
            <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
        </ClaimType>
```